# Not able to handle the com.apollographql.apollo3.exception.ApolloHttpException GraphQl Apolloclient in android

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, graphql, apollo

Iam getting below mentioned exception not able to handle from Android Apollo GraphQL

```
 com.apollographql.apollo3.exception.ApolloHttpException: Http request failed with status code `403`                                                                                               at com.apollographql.apollo3.network.http.HttpNetworkTransport$execute$1.invokeSuspend(HttpNetworkTransport.kt:66)                                                                                                       at com.apollographql.apollo3.network.http.HttpNetworkTransport$execute$1.invoke(Unknown Source:8)                                                                                                   at com.apollographql.apollo3.network.http.HttpNetworkTransport$execute$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)                                                                                                   at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow.collectSafely(Builders.kt:61)
                                                                                                    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.AbstractFlow.collect(Flow.kt:230)                                                                                                    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowOperatorImpl.flowCollect(ChannelFlow.kt:195)                                                                                                     at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowOperator.collect$suspendImpl(ChannelFlow.kt:167)                                                                                                 at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowOperator.collect(Unknown Source:0)                                                                                                   at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ReduceKt.single(Reduce.kt:57)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt.single(Unknown Source:1)
                                                                                                        at com.apollographql.apollo3.ApolloCall.execute(ApolloCall.kt:102)
```

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/essentials/errors

```
 suspend fun getResul() : ApolloResponse<StudentQuery.Data> {
     
        val response = try {
            apolloClient.query(GetStudentQuery()).execute()
        } catch(exception: ApolloHttpException) {
            
            throw exception
        }
        return response
    }
```

App is getting crash's how to handle this exception

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you are rethrowing the exception. What do you expect?

Comment: @zomega App should not crash at any exception with Apollo client. also how to handle from fragment?

Comment: You have to read books or watch YouTube tutorials about Kotlin and Android to get started. You are rethrowing the exception in the line "throw exception". That is why your app crashes.